# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 Preview "SharedCompilationId" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task

Tags: macos, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying run the project with views in separate class library on Mac OSX as described in below article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/01/asp-net-core-2-1-razor-ui-in-class-libraries/

The problem is that I cannot build the class library project with Visual Studio Community 7.4 on Mac OS.

Project builds with command line (donet build) without problems but when I try to build it with Visual Studio it throws two errors:

> `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design/2.1.0-preview1-final/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.Compilation.targets(10,10): Error MSB4064: The "SharedCompilationId" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. (MSB4064)`
>
> `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design/2.1.0-preview1-final/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.Compilation.targets(5,5): Error MSB4063: The "Csc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.  (MSB4063)`

When I change RazorCompileOnBuild to false or remove Content from Content Build project compiles without errors.

Comment: I haven't tried the preview yet, but I'd imagine it's a tooling issue. Once 2.1 is released, Visual Studio will definitely have been updated as well to align with this, but for the time being, it would seem the current version is not capable. You might be able to get it to work if you run it in an instance of Visual Studio from the preview channel, i.e. the tooling may already be present there.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I am bumping up against the same issue.

Answer (score 47):

Go to Nuget Console and add:

`Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.8.2`

You will no longer get above mentioned error.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on the build server but not locally.

The solution:
Install the updated Visual Studio on the build server. In my case 2017.15.4

Answer (score 3):

As I find you can solve this issue in two ways.

**Solution 1**

Add `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` compilers package to the project.

**Solution 2**

Build the project using the command line. `dotnet build`

Comment: i have a 2.2.0 project that gave this error and installed the microsoft.net.compilers for 2.2.0 to match the others core packages and still the same error

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had installed the .NET Core 2.1 SDK, but not the runtime.

Strange how Microsoft don't include the runtime in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you face this problem there are **three** steps you need to take:

1. Ensure that Nuget package and Target Framework match.
2. Ensure that the referenced [runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) and [sdk](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) are installed.
3. Ensure that Visual Studio is up to date.